# How to adjust size of text in a wheelchart and applying a proper filtering using datatool?

Tags: tikz-pgf, datatool

I am very happy with the package `wheelchart` in combination with `datatool`, but I am troubled with three issues:

1. I would like to increase the font size of the text in the outer ring (`Plan`, `Production` etc.). It should be easily readable when looking at it.

[image]

2. I’d like to filter for certain activities (column `category`). This works fine, but I also want to have a version with **no filter**. This is the first wheelchart on the left. It works, but the code has an error – because (so far as I can figure it out) `datatool` wants to have some value in `[]` for filtering the database. It works fine when filtering for a value from the column `category`.

[image]

3. I’d like to get rid of the empty space of the filtered out activities. In other words, the wheelchart should be decreased and has no white space (like in the first wheelchart when there is no filter).

This means that the wheelchart for "Data Stewards" would be quite small, since it only has four rings:
[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=0,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\colorlet{stages}{Blue}
\colorlet{service}{Magenta}
\colorlet{datasteward}{Green}
\colorlet{consulting}{Cyan}
\colorlet{project}{Orange}
\colorlet{natInf}{Purple}


% counter for having slightly different colors for the categories
\newcounter{rpdmCategoryService}\setcounter{rpdmCategoryService}{100}
\newcounter{rpdmCategoryDatasteward}\setcounter{rpdmCategoryDatasteward}{100}
\newcounter{rpdmCategoryConsulting}\setcounter{rpdmCategoryConsulting}{100}
\newcounter{rpdmCategoryProject}\setcounter{rpdmCategoryProject}{100}
\newcounter{rpdmCategoryNFDI}\setcounter{rpdmCategoryNFDI}{100}

%counting the amount of items/activitys to adjust radius of the outer stages
\newcounter{rpdmStagesRadius}
\setcounter{rpdmStagesRadius}{0}

\usepackage{xstring}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rpdmCheckCategory}[1]{%
\IfEqCase{#1}{%
{service}{\addtocounter{rpdmCategoryService}{-5}\def\rpdmSliceColor{service!\therpdmCategoryService}}
{datasteward}{\addtocounter{rpdmCategoryDatasteward}{-5}\def\rpdmSliceColor{datasteward!\therpdmCategoryDatasteward}}
{consulting}{\addtocounter{rpdmCategoryConsulting}{-5}\def\rpdmSliceColor{consulting!\therpdmCategoryConsulting}}
{project}{\addtocounter{rpdmCategoryProject}{-5}\def\rpdmSliceColor{project!\therpdmCategoryProject}}
{natInf}{\addtocounter{rpdmCategoryNFDI}{-5}\def\rpdmSliceColor{natInf!\therpdmCategoryNFDI}}
}[\def\rpdmSliceColor{red}]
}

\usepackage{wheelchart}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{activities.csv}
category,startangle,totalangle,name,begin,end
datasteward,-90,180,project1,2014,2024
service,0,90,project2,2019,
datasteward,-90,180,project3,2019,
natInf,40,280,project4,2020,
natInf,40,280,project5,2020,
natInf,40,280,project6,2020,
service,0,90,project7,2021,
service,0,90,project8,2021,
project,90,270,project9,2021,2024
service,0,90,project10,2023,
service,0,90,project11,2021,
natInf,40,280,project12,2021,
natInf,40,280,project13,2021,
datasteward,-90,180,project14,2019,2023
datasteward,-90,180,project15,2023,
project,90,270,project16,2023,
project,-60,270,project17,2020,2023
project,90,270,project18,2022,
consulting,90,120,project19,2022,
consulting,90,120,project20,2022,
consulting,90,120,project21,2023,
project,0,240,project22,2023,
project,0,240,project23,2023,
\end{filecontents}
\DTLloaddb{activities}{activities.csv}
% RDM stages
\gdef\rdmStages{%
20/stages/Plan,
20/stages/Production,
20/stages/Analysis,
20/stages/Storage,
20/stages/Access,
20/stages/Re-use%
}

% läuft wieder....
\NewDocumentCommand{\RDMstages}{}{%
  \wheelchart[
%explode{1}=1,
value          =1,
gap            =.1,
data           =,
radius         ={2+\therpdmStagesRadius}{4+\therpdmStagesRadius},
arc data       =~\WCvarC~,
arc data dir   ={\WCmidangle<180?1:-1},
arc data pos   =0.5,
arc data style ={text color=white},
slices arrow   ={.5}{0},
]{\rdmStages}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\RDMactivityCircle}{som}{%
\setcounter{rpdmCategoryService}{100}
\setcounter{rpdmCategoryDatasteward}{100}
\setcounter{rpdmCategoryConsulting}{100}
\setcounter{rpdmCategoryProject}{100}
\setcounter{rpdmCategoryNFDI}{100}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \DTLsort{begin,startangle}{activities}%
  \DTLforeach%
  [%
  %For the starred version there should be no filtering
   \IfBooleanTF{#1}{}{\DTLisinlist{\WCcategory}{#3}}% FIX THIS
  ]%
  {activities}{%
\WCcategory =category,%
\WCstart    =startangle,%
\WCend      =totalangle,%
\WCname     =name,%
\WCsince    =begin,%
\WCtil      =end%
}{%
\wheelchart[
for loop start = {\rpdmCheckCategory{\WCcategory}},
for loop end = {\setcounter{rpdmStagesRadius}{\dtlrownum}},
  data=,
  arc data={\WCname},
  arc data dir={\WCmidangle<180?1:-1},
  arc data pos=0.5,
  arc data style={text color=white},
  gap radius=0.05,
  radius={1+\dtlrownum}{2+\dtlrownum},
  slices style={\rpdmSliceColor},
  slices end arc={1}{0},
  slices start arc={1}{0},
  start angle=\WCstart,
  total angle={\WCend}
]{1}}
\RDMstages
\IfValueT{#2}{%
\node[align=center,font=\bfseries, yshift=2em] (title)
    at (current bounding box.north)
    {\Huge #2};}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\RDMactivityCircle*{} % FIX THIS
\RDMactivityCircle[Projects]{project}
\RDMactivityCircle[Consulting]{consulting}
\RDMactivityCircle[National Infrastructures]{natInf}
\RDMactivityCircle[Services and Infrastructures]{service}
\RDMactivityCircle[Data Stewards]{datasteward}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) (which I wrote) loads the package `tikz` so `\usepackage{tikz}` was removed.

The font size of the text in the outer ring can be changed with `|\huge|` in the key `arc data`. The `~` around `\WCvarC` are unnecessary in this MWE.

For the true branch of `\IfBooleanTF`, `\boolean{true}` was added.

Instead of using `\dtlrownum`, the counter `rpdmStagesRadius` is set to `0` at the start of the command `\RDMactivityCircle`. This counter is increased before the command `\wheelchart` inside the fourth argument of `\DTLforeach`. Then the key `for loop end` is not used anymore.

For this MWE, `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}` and `\usepackage{etoolbox}` are unnecessary and these are removed.

The command `\rdmStages` is incorporated in the command `\RDMstages`. Here, `stages` does not need to be repeated each time by using `slices style=stages`. Also the multiple `20` are unnecessary since `value=1` is used. Then `\WCvarC` is replaced by `\WCvarA`.

The key `yshift=2em` is replaced by `above`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{datatool}
\colorlet{stages}{Blue}
\colorlet{service}{Magenta}
\colorlet{datasteward}{Green}
\colorlet{consulting}{Cyan}
\colorlet{project}{Orange}
\colorlet{natInf}{Purple}
%counter for having slightly different colors for the categories
\newcounter{rpdmCategoryService}\setcounter{rpdmCategoryService}{100}
\newcounter{rpdmCategoryDatasteward}\setcounter{rpdmCategoryDatasteward}{100}
\newcounter{rpdmCategoryConsulting}\setcounter{rpdmCategoryConsulting}{100}
\newcounter{rpdmCategoryProject}\setcounter{rpdmCategoryProject}{100}
\newcounter{rpdmCategoryNFDI}\setcounter{rpdmCategoryNFDI}{100}
%counting the amount of items/activities to adjust radius of the outer stages
\newcounter{rpdmStagesRadius}
\setcounter{rpdmStagesRadius}{0}
\usepackage{xstring}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rpdmCheckCategory}[1]{%
\IfEqCase{#1}{%
{service}{\addtocounter{rpdmCategoryService}{-5}\def\rpdmSliceColor{service!\therpdmCategoryService}}
{datasteward}{\addtocounter{rpdmCategoryDatasteward}{-5}\def\rpdmSliceColor{datasteward!\therpdmCategoryDatasteward}}
{consulting}{\addtocounter{rpdmCategoryConsulting}{-5}\def\rpdmSliceColor{consulting!\therpdmCategoryConsulting}}
{project}{\addtocounter{rpdmCategoryProject}{-5}\def\rpdmSliceColor{project!\therpdmCategoryProject}}
{natInf}{\addtocounter{rpdmCategoryNFDI}{-5}\def\rpdmSliceColor{natInf!\therpdmCategoryNFDI}}
}[\def\rpdmSliceColor{red}]
}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{activities.csv}
category,startangle,totalangle,name,begin,end
datasteward,-90,180,project1,2014,2024
service,0,90,project2,2019,
datasteward,-90,180,project3,2019,
natInf,40,280,project4,2020,
natInf,40,280,project5,2020,
natInf,40,280,project6,2020,
service,0,90,project7,2021,
service,0,90,project8,2021,
project,90,270,project9,2021,2024
service,0,90,project10,2023,
service,0,90,project11,2021,
natInf,40,280,project12,2021,
natInf,40,280,project13,2021,
datasteward,-90,180,project14,2019,2023
datasteward,-90,180,project15,2023,
project,90,270,project16,2023,
project,-60,270,project17,2020,2023
project,90,270,project18,2022,
consulting,90,120,project19,2022,
consulting,90,120,project20,2022,
consulting,90,120,project21,2023,
project,0,240,project22,2023,
project,0,240,project23,2023,
\end{filecontents}
\DTLloaddb{activities}{activities.csv}
%RDM stages
\NewDocumentCommand{\RDMstages}{}{%
  \wheelchart[
    arc data=|\huge|\WCvarA,
    arc data dir={\WCmidangle<180?1:-1},
    arc data pos=0.5,
    arc data style={text color=white},
    data=,
    gap=.1,
    radius={2+\therpdmStagesRadius}{4+\therpdmStagesRadius},
    slices arrow={.5}{0},
    slices style=stages,
    value=1
  ]{Plan,Production,Analysis,Storage,Access,Re-use}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\RDMactivityCircle}{som}{%
  \setcounter{rpdmCategoryService}{100}
  \setcounter{rpdmCategoryDatasteward}{100}
  \setcounter{rpdmCategoryConsulting}{100}
  \setcounter{rpdmCategoryProject}{100}
  \setcounter{rpdmCategoryNFDI}{100}
  \setcounter{rpdmStagesRadius}{0}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \DTLsort{begin,startangle}{activities}%
  \DTLforeach%
    [%
      %For the starred version there should be no filtering
      \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\boolean{true}}{\DTLisinlist{\WCcategory}{#3}}
    ]%
    {activities}%
    {%
      \WCcategory=category,%
      \WCstart=startangle,%
      \WCend=totalangle,%
      \WCname=name,%
      \WCsince=begin,%
      \WCtil=end%
    }%
    {%
      \addtocounter{rpdmStagesRadius}{1}%
      \wheelchart[
        arc data=\WCname,
        arc data dir={\WCmidangle<180?1:-1},
        arc data pos=0.5,
        arc data style={text color=white},
        before slices=\rpdmCheckCategory{\WCcategory},
        data=,
        gap radius=0.05,
        radius={1+\therpdmStagesRadius}{2+\therpdmStagesRadius},
        slices end arc={1}{0},
        slices start arc={1}{0},
        slices style=\rpdmSliceColor,
        start angle=\WCstart,
        total angle=\WCend
      ]{1}%
    }%
  \RDMstages%
  \IfValueT{#2}{\node[align=center,font=\bfseries,above] at (current bounding box.north) {\Huge #2};}%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\RDMactivityCircle*{}
\RDMactivityCircle[Projects]{project}
\RDMactivityCircle[Consulting]{consulting}
\RDMactivityCircle[National Infrastructures]{natInf}
\RDMactivityCircle[Services and Infrastructures]{service}
\RDMactivityCircle[Data Stewards]{datasteward}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was hoping you’d see the question. Thank for the solution and +100 for refactoring it!

Comment: @lukascbossert The key `for loop start` is replaced by the key `before slices`. The command `\wheelchart` executes several for loops in which the key `for loop start` is used. Hence this key is not suited to be used to increase counters, although version 2.0 did not give an error. But version 3.0 gives an error with the code in the original answer. Because of all this, the key `for loop start` is replaced by the key `before slices`.